# How do I indicate a range in a variable in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet in which I created a custom show/hide columns function in the Script Editor.  I want to show/hide columns 1, 3, and 14 through 30.

This is the code I tried:

```
var colsCheck = [1,3,14:30];
```

But when I save, I get this error:

> Missing ] after element list. (line 4, file "Code")

So I tried this:

```
var colsCheck = [1,3,14-30];
```

This doesn't give an error but it doesn't hide columns 14-30, either.  Is there a way to indicate I want columns 14 through 30 without typing `14, 15, 16, 17...`?

I am trying to Google this but I don't know the terminology well enough to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: You will need to put `14-30` in quotes.  Either single or double quotes, which will make the array element a string.  Then your code will need to have a loop, and use the first value as the start and the last value as the stop value.  `var thisRange = colsCheck[i];  if (typeof thisRange === 'string') {var i,startVal,stopVal; startVal = thisRange.slice(0.thisRange.indexOf("-"); for (i=0;i<stopValue;i++ {thisNumber = startVal + i;}}`

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is really "on topic."  Or it it's not, what other community you would use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that what you're writing in the Script Editor is [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), so your script must conform to JavaScript syntax.

`14:30` does not, hence the error `Missing ] after element list`. `14-30` can very well be legal JavaScript, but it will be interpreted as `14 minus 30`, so it will result in `-16`.

If you want an array with column numbers, you can populate it programmatically. First, let's list the single columns you want:

```
var colsCheck = [1, 3];
```

Then, let's loop through the numbers 14 to 30, inclusive, and append (`push`) those to the array:

```
for (var col = 14; col <= 30; col++) {
  colsCheck.push(col);
}
```

At this point, your array will be `[1, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]`.

Now, I suspect you will have to expand your script a whole lot in order to accomplish what you *really* want. I suggest you try to familiarize yourself with JavaScript, through an online course like [this one from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps). Then, learn how JavaScript is used in Google Scripts with [Google's tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles).